# partykit - How to plot a glmtree without overlapping of terminal nodes?

Tags: r, plot, tree, glm, party

I would like to plot a tree resulting from glmtree (partykit package). Unfortunately, the terminal nodes are overlapping and the labels of the graphs are no longer displayed properly.

The code that generates the tree is this one:

```
library(partykit)
library(aVirtualTwins)

data(sepsis)
attach(sepsis)

data <- cbind(y = survival, trt = as.factor(THERAPY), sepsis[,3:13])
formula <- as.formula(paste("y ~ trt", paste(names(sepsis[,3:13]), 
                            collapse = " + "), sep = " | "))
fit <- glmtree(formula, data, family = binomial)

plot(fit)

detach(sepsis)
```

Is there a way to customize the output of plot() in order to avoid overlapping of the terminal nodes?

Here is a picture of what I mean:
[image: Here is a picture of what I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot()` output for `glmtree` objects (and also other `partykit` objects) is customizable through panel functions for all aspects of the tree (inner nodes, terminal nodes, edges, ...). The panel function employed by default for this kind of tree is `node_bivplot()` which has a number of arguments that can be tweaked. See `?node_bivplot` for details. The relevant option here is `ylines` that you can increase to `2`, for example.

To pass arguments to the terminal panel function`tp_args` can be used:

```
plot(fit, tp_args = list(ylines = 2))
```

[image: glmtree]

Comment: Thanks, Achim, for your support. Now I understand, how to pass arguments to the panel functions. Additionally, I changed some names of covariates and this is, what I came up with:

plot(fit.glmtree, tp_args = list(ylines = 1, margins = c(1.5, 1.2, 1.5, 2.5)), ep_args = list(digits = 1))

Comment: Great, glad it could be solved. Could you please also accept the answer here on StackOverflow that it gets flagged as solved by the system?